# porting uart based C program to android, any good way?

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, uart

I need port a C program to android. The C program is uart based. I managed to build this program using NDK compiler, but when it runs in android, the access to uart /dev/ttyACM0 is denied.
So there are several ways to do that:
1) building the C program as whole, rooting android system and allow it to access uart. using some IPC method to allow android app to talk with this C program. is that possible?

2) using android USB/cdc acm interface, build C program as NDK native lib, and called by java.  it requires a refactory of the C program as it is not designed as module. the question is the C program will call uart interface which is Java based. can the java call JNI for C native and then C native call java (uart part) again?

any other options?

Comment: First make sure you can achieve basic communication between Android and your device, for example via USB host mode and implementing CDC/ACM code inside an application.  Then you can decide if you want to port your C code to java, adapt it so you can call its re-named main() in a thread (but make sure you have a way to reset process-static state!) , or run it as a distinct process.  You should be able to use either a pair of pipes or a unix domain socket as a proxy for a serial port with minor changes (especially if you can hard code the line settings - baud rate, etc).

Comment: thanks Chris, yes, I get the basic CDC/ACM communicating between my android and my MCU via USB connection. 
the problem is this method requires rooting the android system as it needs access the /dev/ttyACM0.  So a more flexible way is using the android USB driver to perform the UART part, but build rest parts of the C code as the native lib.   The question is, it may require java(UI) call native C and then native C call Java(uart) code. I am new to Android, not sure how to do that.